# JSON retornando <html>

Tags: php, android

Estou retornando um JSON de um servidor utilizando PHP com o simples código:

```
<?php
$response = array();
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Estou recebendo a resposta através de um aplicativo android, porém com o seguinte erro:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value `<html>` of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Suspeito que o servidor esteja enviando algo a mais junto com o JSON. O que faça para evitar isso?

Comment: Seria bom testar o conteúdo retornado. Pode ter ocorrido alguma exceção e a página de erro do apache estar sendo retornada, por exemplo. Você consegue simular a chamada de um browser ou de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Com certeza está sendo retornada alguma exceção... Chutaria erro 500 ou 404

Comment: É isso ai, o apache está enviando uma página de erro ao invés do JSON. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## O Erro recebido

De uma forma genérica, o erro `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException ...` refere-se à incapacidade de processar o JSON.

Para o teu caso em particular, pode-se ler na mensagem de erro:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Que traduzido:

> Erro ao processar dados org.json.JSONException: Valor  do tipo java.lang.String não pode ser convertido para JSONObject

Que nos diz que está a ser enviado uma `string` ao invés de um objecto, como seria esperado.

## Lidar com o erro

Uma forma de lidares com o erro em cenários deste género é envolveres o teu código num `try...catch` de forma a *tentares* trabalhar os dados recebidos enquanto capaz de apanhar os eventuais erros de uma forma que te permita lidar com eles:

```
try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
    String succes = jobj.getString("success");
    ...
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // ups, correu mal... vamos ver o que aconteceu
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```